# Using openSSL in a software and exporting it

Tags: cryptography

The OpenSSL license talks about crypto laws in various countries.  I have seen many apps using https. So, do all of them take a license or something? What kind of license can I choose to give to take no liability (in case I distribute commercial software made with SSL).

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: India I am in and I am mainly concerned about sending to US,EUisrael and Russia.(It will be just an app using https requests on play store).

Answer (score 2):

Those crypto laws are typically not centered around copyright, which means that there is no copyright license, open-source or not, that can limit your liability when breaking those laws.

Those crypto laws are typically centered around the idea that having better cryptography that your enemy gives your military an advantage. And having a military advantage is a good thing when a war starts.
Those laws restrict the export of the actual cryptography software (i.e. the SSL library itself), but not of software that just uses a secure connection to protect its communication.

This means that if your app does not include the SSL library itself but rather asks the OS to create a secure connection for them, then the app is not restricted by the crypto laws.

If you do include the SSL library in your app (or implement cryptographic algorithms yourself), then you need to carefully look at the export laws for both your country and the countries where your repository and servers are hosted. You may need to restrict from which countries those servers can be accessed.
Licenses to export your app under the crypto laws do exist, but that is typically a license for a single sale.

Comment: So does open SSL do it itself or ask the OS.One more thing many apps have ads ,those might be using https so do all those apps need a liscence or has Google taken one for Android?

Comment: Basically can I use OpenSSL in a closed source commercial app assuming appache v2 liscence with crypto software?Moreover games made in game engines supporting https should also come under this.

Comment: @compenthusiast, do you actively distribute OpenSSL with your app, or do you expect that Google or the device manufacturer has already installed it on the device?

Comment: I have actually not made an app yet. I will make and I want to know all legal aspects beforehand. I have mainly a want to implement HTTPS TLS to communicate between a server and the client.I will use the GODOT game engine(MIT) which uses mbedssl or write an openSSL plugin.My basic question is :::::::: If my app makes https requests does it need to get export liscence in India? ::::::::::: From chart on

Comment: Wikipedia I found out suoth koraea, South Africa and Russia restrict importing cryptography(and others).If it's not strong encryption can I distribute my app on lay store or I must get a liscence or leave out some countries?

Comment: Restrictions_on_the_import_of_cryptography

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States

Comment: I also read in one article that lower than 56 bit encryption is allowed , is it so?

Comment: https://medium.com/@cyberpeacealliance/what-is-export-import-control-on-encryption-3d8dbea49629

Comment: @compenthusiast, if you really want to know all the legal aspects, talk to a local lawyer who knows about this stuff. Don't trust random strangers on the internet for it.

Comment: Ok.I haven't released anything yet I am assuming(I will recheck with law) that less than 56 bit encryption is allowed.

Comment: @compenthusiast just so we're clear, 56 bit asymmetric encryption at this point is functionally equivalent to plaintext; over twenty years ago, you could brute-force a 56-bit key in three days.  I recommend focussing on what Bart has to say about how *exporting apps that link to good crypto libraries* and *exporting good crypto* are **not the same thing**.